Can I use a MOSFET for battery over-discharge protection?
Since turning on the MOSFET requires certain Vgs, it is possible to use this mechanism to protect the battery from over-discharging? If so, how do i pick the Vgs when the minimum discharge voltage of the battery is 2.5V.
My understanding for p-channel MOSFET as an ideal diode is that when the drain voltage is 4.2V, gate is grounded, and the voltage drop of body diode is 0.8V, the source voltage get 3.5V. Hence, MOSFET is in on-state. Body diode becomes reverse-biased. Source voltage increases to as identical as the drain voltage. From on to off state, the source voltage needs to drop below Vgs. Once it drops, the drain voltage requires extra voltage to overcome the body diode forward voltage.
If I choose a MOSFET that requires minimum Vgs of -2.5V. Then, the battery needs extra 0.8V to activate the MOSFET? Could this waste some capacity of the battery? But when i get lower than 2.5V, it could possible lose the purpose of protecting over-discharge.
Will this SQ3419CEV do the job?


Since you cannot turn off the body diode, the battery will be drained down to 0.8 V anyway. Swap drain and source and calculate again.

Remember that a MOSFET doesn't turn on instantly at the threshold voltage; between threshold and fully on there's a range of linear operation (wherein the FET will have high effective on resistance) that may be as large as several volts. So if you want a sharp cutoff, a MOSFET alone is not going to do it for you.
